# How can I show custom view as marker by default on Charts in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using Charts SDK to show Line graph in my app. I want to display marker for some coordinates of graph by default, (i.e, when graph is loaded then by default a custom view marker should be displayed above some coordinates of graph).

I am able to do it when graph is touched and delegate method of Chart SDK is called

```
chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)
```

But, how can i achieve this by default without touching the graph .

I also used `LineChartDataSet` but it shows circle for those values, but i want to show some custom view instead of circle.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom icon for data entries by using `ChartDataEntry(x:, y:, icon:)` initializer

```
let entry = ChartDataEntry(x: 2, y: 12, icon: UIImage(systemName: "airplane.circle.fill"))
```

Make sure you have also `lineDataSet.drawIconsEnabled = true`

```
let lineDataSet = LineChartDataSet(....)
lineDataSet.drawIconsEnabled = true
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as answered by @SamB.
I am using Charts SDK in my iOS project. Charts SDK provides functionality to pass image

```
ChartDataEntry(x: 10, y: 10, data: 20, icon: UIImage(systemName: "imageName"))
```

In Data field you can paas the position value of those point.